# How do I fetch and display data in a html table using javascript fetch method?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, fetch-api

I am still new to javascript and I need your help.I am trying to fetch JSON data from an API and display it in a table using html.So far I have been able to display the data using html but when I try to organise it in a table it does not workSo how can I display the data in a html table?.Here is the html table:

```
    `enter code here`<!DOCTYPE html>
    `enter code here`<html>
    `enter code here`<head>
            `enter code here`<title>Scorejedi</title>   
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
       <body>
          <div class="container">
          <h1>ScoreBoard</h1>
          <table border = "1">
             <div class="title-box">
             <tr>
                <td><div class="league">
                <img id="leagueLogo">
                <p id="leagueName">League Name</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>                
                  <div class="team">
                  <img  id="homeLogo" >
                  <p id="homeName">Team name</p>
                  </div>
             </td>
            <td>
               <div>
               <p id="goals"></p>
               </div>

            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="team">
               <img id="awayLogo">
               <p id="awayName">Team name</p>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         </div>
      </table>
      <hr>
            <div id="matchTable" class="matches-table">

            </div>
      </div>

         
         
      </table>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

here is the javascript code:

```
    //getting the DOM elements
var elapsedTime = document.querySelector("#elapsed");
var homeTeamImage = document.querySelector("#homeLogo");
var homeTeamName = document.querySelector("#homeName");
var awayTeamImage = document.querySelector("#awayLogo");
var awayTeamName = document.querySelector("#awayName");
var lastMatchGoal = document.querySelector("#goals");
var leagueName= document.querySelector("#leagueName");
var leagueCountry= document.querySelector("#leagueCountry");
var leagueLogo= document.querySelector("#leagueLogo");
var matchTable = document.querySelector("#matchTable");



//the functions to create an element
function addMatchTile(data){
    //createing the tile div
    var matchtile = document.createElement('div');
    matchtile.classList.add("match-tile");

    //creating the home match box
    var homeTeam = document.createElement('div');
    homeTeam.classList.add("team");
    //creating the image and the text
    var homeTileTeamName = document.createElement('p');
    homeTileTeamName.innerHTML = data['teams']['home']['name'];
    var homeTileTeamLogo = document.createElement('img');
    homeTileTeamLogo.src=data['teams']['home']['logo'];
    homeTeam.appendChild(homeTileTeamLogo);
    homeTeam.appendChild(homeTileTeamName);

    var awayTeam = document.createElement('div');
    awayTeam.classList.add("team");
    //creating the image and the text
    var awayTileTeamName = document.createElement('p');
    awayTileTeamName.innerHTML = data['teams']['away']['name'];
    var awayTileTeamLogo = document.createElement('img');
    awayTileTeamLogo.src=data['teams']['away']['logo'];
    awayTeam.appendChild(awayTileTeamLogo);
    awayTeam.appendChild(awayTileTeamName);
    //creating the league info
    var leagueInfo = document.createElement('div');
    matchtile.classList.add("league");
    //creating the image and the text
    var officialLeagueName = document.createElement('p');
    officialLeagueName.innerHTML = data['league']['name'];
    var officialLeagueLogo = document.createElement('img');
    officialLeagueLogo.src =data['league']['logo'];
    leagueInfo.appendChild(officialLeagueName);
    leagueInfo.appendChild(officialLeagueLogo);


    //createing the score
    var score = document.createElement('p');
    score.innerHTML = data['goals']['home'] + " - " + data['goals']['away'];

    //append all the element to the parent
    matchtile.appendChild(leagueInfo);
    matchtile.appendChild(homeTeam);
    matchtile.appendChild(score);
    matchtile.appendChild(awayTeam);

    matchTable.appendChild(matchtile);
}
//fetching the data
fetch("https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures?date=2021-09-03", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "v3.football.api-sports.io",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "7c8b6208c94aaaaf7861641703244162"
    }
})
.then(response => response.json().then(data => {
    var matchesList = data['response'];
    var fixture = matchesList[0]['fixture'];
    var goals = matchesList[0]['goals'];
    var teams = matchesList[0]['teams'];
    var league = matchesList[0]['league'];
    console.log(matchesList.length);
   //Now let's set our first match
   leagueName= league['name'];
   leagueLogo= league['logo'];
   
   homeTeamImage.src = teams['home']['logo'];
   homeTeamName.innerHTML = teams['home']['name'];
   awayTeamImage.src = teams['away']['logo'];
   awayTeamName.innerHTML = teams['away']['name'];
   lastMatchGoal.innerHTML = goals['home']+ " - " + goals['away'];

   for(var i = 1; i<matchesList.length;i++){
       addMatchTile(matchesList[i]);
   }

}))
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do it is to use an HTML `template` element and regex

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Here's some code.

```
<table class="table" id="foo">
    <thead>
        <th>Column</th>
        <th>headers</th>
        <th>go</th>
        <th>here</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tbody>
</table>

<template id="dataRow">
    <tr>
        <td>{value1}</td>
        <td>{value2}</td>
        <td>{value3}</td>
        <td>{value4}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

This sets up the markup we'll be modifying and placing in `<tbody>`.

```
<script>
    function loadAndRenderData() {
        var jsonData = fetchData();

        const template = document.querySelector("#dataRow").innerHTML;
        for(let item of jsonData)
        {
            let t = template;

            t = t.replace(/{value1}/g, item.value1;
            t = t.replace(/{value2}/g, item.value2;
            t = t.replace(/{value3}/g, item.value3;
            t = t.replace(/{value4}/g, item.value4;

            document.querySelector("#foo tbody").innerHtml += t;
        }
    }
</script>
```

We just append the content of the template with replaced values to the `tbody` in the table.

Note: I did this years ago and I haven't tested this code, so no guarantee it works.